# Ignore leading "the" in alphabetic index in Word file

Tags: microsoft-word

MS Word allows the author to mark keywords in the text that are to be listed with page reference in an auto-generated index. A marked keyword will be given the following invisible indicator:

> As a matter of fact, the White House{ XE "White House" } is blue.

The indicator `{ XE "White House" }` adds the words `White House` to the index under letter `w` in the alphabetic order.

Now, I often have keywords that ought to be shown with a leading `the`. The above example would more accurately and appropriately be written as:

> As a matter of fact, the White House{ XE "the White House" } is blue.

with the indicator `{ XE "the White House" }`. But, then it will be listed under letter `t`. I would like it to still be listed under letter `w`, eventhough the leading `the` is displayed.

Is this possible to achieve?